# Downloadable free movies API

Tags: data-request, api, film

Looking for an API with free movies and download links for them. Something like this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_films
But an API and with download links.

Comment: "Free movies" and "open content films" don't overlap 100% (for example, Youtube hosts full length movies, but they don't count as "open content".

Comment: @philshem indeed. I'm looking for an API with movies that are free to download and play. Youtube is not an option as they don't allow downloads.